# Dynamically load WordPress post content into DIV using HTML select, query, and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to use WordPress and AJAX to display content (title and ACF fields) from a single post object in a page template using a HTML `<select>` input with no button or submit. The single post would change each time a different option is selected. The page would need to display the most recent post by default in the div when the page is loaded.

I have included the code I have implemented so far.

My knowledge of AJAX is limited.

Any tips or suggestions?

**functions.php**

```
function theme_global_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sendout-ajax', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/sendouts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'sendout-ajax', 'frontEndAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax_nonce') ));

}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_global_script' );

add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts', 'get_sendout_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_posts', 'get_sendout_posts');   
function get_sendout_posts() {
    // Query Arguments
    // Select unlimited published posts from category 101 and order by date
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'nopaging' => true,
        'numberposts' => '-1',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'cat' => 101,
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxposts = new WP_Query( $args );
    $response = '';

    // The Query
    // If query is has results, load the sendouts template part
    if ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
            $ajaxposts->the_post();
            $response .= get_template_part( 'template-includes', 'sendouts' );
        }
    } else {
        $response .= get_template_part( 'none' );
    }

    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

**Sendout template part HTML**

The `$post->ID` and `$post->name` would be returned from the WordPress query

```
<select id="" name="" class="sendout-select">
    <option value="[$post->ID]">[$post-name]</option>
    <option value="[$post->ID]">[$post-name]</option>
    <option value="[$post->ID]">[$post-name]</option>
</select>
<div class="sendout-container">
    <!-- Load Post object here -->
</div>
```

**AJAX JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".sendout-select" ).change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: frontEndAjax.ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                action : 'get_sendout_posts'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });  
    });
});
```